# If record exists dont insert

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, asp.net, database

I'm trying something out but cant figure it out. So what i'm trying is that if the user inputs something inside txtISN and it already exists inside of the database, the record wont be inserted. I also want a error msg to pop up when a record wasnt inserted and when a record is inserted I want an message to pop up saying that the record was inserted succesfully.

Thanks for the help y'all!

```
 string _connStr = @"Data Source = EJQ7FRN; Initial Catalog = BES; Integrated Security = True";
                string _query = "INSERT INTO [BES_S] (ISN,Titel,Name) values (@ISN,@Titel,@Name)";
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connStr))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand())
                    {
                        comm.Connection = conn;
                        comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        comm.CommandText = _query;
                        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ISN", txtISN.Text);
                        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Titel",txtTitel.Text);
                        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtName.Text);
                        try
                        {
                            conn.Open();
                            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                        catch (SqlException ex)
                        {

                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Do you have a primary key on that table?

Comment: You first have to query the database (Select statement) to determine if there is any data before inserting.

Comment: Can you explain why you use the tag MySql while your code uses the classes for Sql Server? Please be more careful in your use of tags...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your query a bit, but you can use MySql's [DUAL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html#idm139774709444880) keyword to do this:

```
string _connStr = @"Data Source = EJQ7FRN; Initial Catalog = BES; Integrated Security = True";
string _query = "INSERT INTO [BES_S] (ISN,Titel,Name) ";
_query = _query + " SELECT @ISN, @Titel, @Name FROM DUAL";
_query = _query + " WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT ISN WHERE ISN=@ISN)";

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connStr))
{
    using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand())
    {
        comm.Connection = conn;
        comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        comm.CommandText = _query;
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ISN", txtISN.Text);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Titel",txtTitel.Text);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtName.Text);
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

`DUAL` is like a dummy table that you can use to `SELECT` from.

Comment: It seems that you have followed my error. Tags for MySql code for Sql Server

Comment: This works. Thank you! One more thing though, how do I display a error message when the record isnt inserted?

Comment: @FranciscoIvens - There are several ways. After your do your insert, do a `SELECT ROW_COUNT();`. If its `0`, then you know it was a duplicate. It's hard to determine from the code you provided. Is this WebForms or MVC?

Comment: WebForms. Thank you for the help by the way, appreciate ya :)!

Comment: I am very troubled from the fact that OP says that this works. How is it possible when Sql Server has no concept of a DUAL dummy table ?

Comment: @Steve - It's tagged with MySql, so I'm assuming he's using MySql

Comment: Sure, I had posted an answer as well, but then I noticed the connection string for Sql Server and the classes from the SqlClient library. This is why I have deleted my answer for MySql. If he uses really MySql then the classes used cannot work at all. Nothing wrong in your answer if were used with a MySqlCommand, MySqlConnection etc... but how his this code _works_ against a Sql Server db is a mistery.

Answer (score 0):

Let the database take care of this using a unique constraint/index:

```
alter table bes_s add constraint unq_bes_ISN unique (ISN);
```

This will cause the database to generate an error if a duplicate `ISN` is inserted.  You can put one or more columns for the unique constraint (in case this single column is not the exact definition of uniqueness).